# scipy with enthought canopy

Tags: python, scipy, enthought, canopy

I am evaluating the Enthought package. I installed the 32bit canopy (downloaded from https://www.enthought.com/downloads/) in Ubuntu.

```
$ sudo bash canopy-1.0.1-rh5-32.sh
```

Upon testing I don't see scipy in `/usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages`:

```
$ /usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/bin/python 
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 32-bit | (default, Mar 25 2013, 15:45:37) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scipy


>>> from pylab import*
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 265, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  File "/usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 97, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wxagg.py", line 23, in <module>
    import backend_wx    # already uses wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')
  File "/usr/local/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.rh5-x86/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(missingwxversion)


ImportError: Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxversion, which was not found.
```

Please help me: how can install the Python Canopy (including scipy, matplotlib etc.)? Do I have to manually install them? I thought the installer shell script installed all these automatically. Am I missing something?

```
$ uname -a
Linux sree 3.0.0-32-generic-pae #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 21 16:09:48 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scipy` is installed into a different [virtual environment](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment) (`~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/`). In general, you should be running the Python available at `~/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python` as described [here](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/faq.html#where-are-all-of-the-python-packages-in-my-user-python-environment). Also look at [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-s-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-) for information on how to make Canopy your default Python