# Canopy, "ImportError: cannot import name scimath

Tags: python, macos, scipy, canopy

I' m currently using Canopy for its amount of scientific packages but I use the Ipython shell from the bash shell to write interactively. When I try importing numpy or scipy interactively I get the following error report:

```
In [4]: import scipy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-4dc45f4c0083> in <module>()
----> 1 import scipy

/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py in <module>()
     68 __all__ = ['test']
     69
---> 70 from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
     71 if show_numpy_config is None:
     72     raise ImportError("Cannot import scipy when running from numpy source directory.")

/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    166         return loader(*packages, **options)
    167
--> 168     from . import add_newdocs
    169     __all__ = ['add_newdocs', 'ModuleDeprecationWarning']
    170

/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14
     15 ###############################################################################

/Users/nick/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
     15 from .ufunclike import *
     16
---> 17 from . import scimath as emath
     18 from .polynomial import *
     19 #import convertcode

ImportError: cannot import name scimath
```

However when I import it from the canopy ipython prompt everything is working fine. 
Is there a workaround on that?
The Canopy edition is 1.3, and the operating system is is OSX 10.9.2.

Thanks,
Nikos

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136122/scipy-with-enthought-canopy) and the accepted answer.

Comment: What is `env` in your terminal, and `sys.path` in your terminal ipython?