# Problems importing using iPython Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to learn how to use iPython Notebooks and am running into a problem importing numpy or matplotlib. When I try to have a cell as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

and press shift + enter: I am returned with the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-deb84735ddff> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 import numpy as np

/Users/jakehuneau/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
    177 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    178 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 179 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
    180 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
    181 

/Users/jakehuneau/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py in <module>()
     30 from weakref import ref, WeakKeyDictionary
     31 
---> 32 import numpy as np
     33 import numpy.ma as ma
     34 

/Users/jakehuneau/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>()
    166         return loader(*packages, **options)
    167 
--> 168     from . import add_newdocs
    169     __all__ = ['add_newdocs', 'ModuleDeprecationWarning']
    170 

/Users/jakehuneau/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

/Users/jakehuneau/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
     15 from .ufunclike import *
     16 
---> 17 from . import scimath as emath
     18 from .polynomial import *
     19 #import convertcode

ImportError: cannot import name scimath
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo pip install scimath`

If it doesn't work then check this out it should help :

[scipy with enthought canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136122/scipy-with-enthought-canopy)

Comment: The link doesn't really pertain to me I don't think

Comment: The error is quite similar, give it another look ? You may find something of use in the comments or answers.